# Ajax cross domain request fail to set headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors

First thing first, this is my first project with an cross domain ajax request.
Now, i have a test page with just a button, an input box and jquery.
What i want to do is send the ajax request to another domani ( i have username and passwod fot this, but i don't know it i have to use it and how) and pass a query, then print the result.

This is my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    $("#btn").on("click", function(){

    var searchRequest = $("#testSearch").val();

    var url = {"https://vk.com/search?c%5Bq%5D="};

    var musicSearchRequest = searchRequest + "&c%5Bsection%5D=audio";
    var vkLogin = new XMLHttpRequest();

    vkLogin.open("GET", url + musicSearchRequest, true);
    vkLogin.send();

    $.ajax({        
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: musicSearchRequest,
        success: function(){console.log("ok");},
        error: function (){console.log("no");}
    }); 

    $("#result").html(vkLogin.responseText);
    console.log(vkLogin.responseText);

});
});
```

and this is the html ( i don't think is really important, but i'll copy anyway):

```
<button id="btn">click</button>
<input type="text" id="testSearch"></input>
<div id="result"></div>
```

now, on click, this is the result printed into my debug console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://vk.com/search?c%5Bq%5D=katy%20perry&c%5Bsection%5D=audio. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I searched a bit about the CORS, but just because i'm a beginner, i'd like someone to explain step by step what to do next to fix this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how CORS works.  Here's a good explanation: https://vk.com/search?c%5Bq%5D=

The error message:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

is talking about the header received *from* vk.com.  Unless you control the server at vk.com (and it sounds like you don't), you can't modify the headers that the vk.com server is returning to your app.  So this isn't going to work for you.